# T4 - A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, t4, css

I get error in the last line started with `string firstLine`:

```
<#+
    int Year = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow.Year);
    int Month = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow.Month);
    int Day = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow.Day);

    int RevisionNumber = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(2013,1,1)).TotalDays;

    string multiLine = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\kozub.sebastian\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\Ris\\RisSystem\\RisSystem\\Properties\\AssemblyInfo.cs");
    string firstLine = multiLine.Substring(0, multiLine.IndexOf('\n'));
#>
```

The error is:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Last two lines works perfectly in normal C# files of my project.

Comment: They will work correctly when used as *variables*, but not as fields.

Comment: The [C# specification (10.4.5.2 Instance field initialization)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645759%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) has some more info - "it is a compile-time error for a variable initializer to reference any instance member through a simple-name" - so an instance field cannot reference any other instance fields (but it can reference constants)

Comment: I am just too stupid.. Please just tell how to write this one line :/

Comment: If you need these to be fields with initialisers, you must make multiLine static: it would be preferable though to initialise these fields in the constructor.

Comment: I didn't know that <#+ #> create class. I have changed to <# #> and everything is ok. Thanks for prompts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [T4 - Error 60: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961295/t4-error-60-a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `<#+ #>`. Adding `+` after `<#` says that the code inside is part of the class and fields of a class should be initialized with static members, constants, etc or using class constructor.

To treat the code as a procedural scripting the code should be inserted inside
`<# #>` marks.